# Cmake match beginning of string

Tags: cmake

I am getting some compile definitions from an external library. Unfortunately, they provide a list that sometimes starts with a leading semi-colon. For example:

```
;-Dfoo;Dbar
```

I think this is crashing the build command later in the process. I thought that I could simply remove potential leading semi-colons with this regex:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "^;" "" stripped_defs ${defs})
```

but the problem is that Cmake seems to be ignoring the carrot ^ which signifies the start of the string, with the consequence being that all semi-colons are deleted. That is, I am getting the output

```
-Dfoo-Dbar
```

when I want

```
-Dfoo;-Dbar
```

Comment: Looks like you ${defs} is a list. ";" list separator in cmake. So you'd better to use foreach and drop empty string or convert list to string before replace with list transform.

Comment: @SergeiNikulov There are better alternatives to the `foreach` loop, e.g. the one mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As Sergei points out, the problem is that my `defs` variable was being interpreted as a list, not a string. So the regex was acting on each element of the list individually. All I need to do to force the string interpretation is to add quotes. Specifically, instead of

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "^;" "" stripped_defs ${defs})
```

I should have had

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "^;" "" stripped_defs "${defs}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a regular expression in this case, using list operations to delete empty elements would be my preferred approach in this case:

```
set(stripped_defs ${defs})
list(REMOVE_ITEM stripped_defs "")
```

This may involve one more command, but it's easier to understand what the snippet does.